Can I make the result of `match`ing on a `const` expression be `const` too?
This code does not compile, since rustc claims that f would need to be const:
const FOO: Option<u32> = None;

fn implementation_with_const<const V: u32>() {
    println!("Got {}", V);
}

fn implementation_without_const() {
    println!("Did not get a constant");
}

fn main() {
    match FOO {
        Some(f) => implementation_with_const::<{f}>(),
        None => implementation_without_const(),
    };
}

To all appearances, f satisfies all conditions of being const.  Is there some way I can rewrite my code so that what I'm trying to do is possible?  (In my real application, FOO is a constant defined in a library based on information about the target machine, and the argument of implementation_with_const() does need to be statically known, so I cannot simply inline it, or turn the const parameter into a regular one.)
Using the unstable feature #![feature(const_option)] and replacing {f} with {FOO.unwrap()} causes a compile failure if FOO is None since both branches of the match are evaluated regardless of FOO.

f itself is not a constant, you ask too much to the compiler here haha, anyway, your example make no sense, the option here is useless

Unfortunately I don't believe it is possible, but it will be possible with a hypothetical language feature const if (similar to C++ if constexpr).

@Stargateur As I said in the post, in my real application, FOO is defined in an external crate based on information about the target machine.  I cannot inline it.

we would need more practical information about this crate and what you need to do to provide an answer to you. For now the answer is just "can't".

It's a bit hacky and requires you to have a const way of constructing the inner type, but this should work.
fn main() {
    const FOO_UNWRAP: u32 = if let Some(f) = FOO { f } else { 0 };
    if FOO.is_some() {
        implementation_with_const::<FOO_UNWRAP>();
    } else {
        implementation_without_const();
    }
}

